# zeep SOAP client unexpected double base64 encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, zeep

Please help me understand why value in my request gets encoded to base64 twice:

relevant parts of wsdl, that I use:

```
<wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.blabla.com/">
         <xsd:element name="createHeaderSecurityRequest" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>

 <wsdl:message name="createHeaderSecurityRequestMessage">
      <wsdl:part element="tns:createHeaderSecurityRequest" name="parameters"/>
   </wsdl:message>

<wsdl:operation name="createHeaderSecurity">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:createHeaderSecurityRequestMessage"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:createHeaderSecurityResponseMessage"/>
         <wsdl:fault message="tns:faultMessage" name="createHeaderSecurityFaultMessage"/>
/wsdl:operation>
```

my code:

```
from zeep import Client
message = 'my message, that needs to be encoded in base64 only once'
wsdl = 'http://xxxxxxx?wsdl'
client = Client(wsdl)
request = client.create_message(client.service, 'createHeaderSecurity', message.encode())
```

what I get(message automatically encoded to base64 twice): request =

```
<soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <ns0:createHeaderSecurityRequest xmlns:ns0="http://www.blabla.com/">YlhrZ2JXVnpjMkZuWlN3Z2RHaGhkQ0J1WldWa2N5QjBieUJpWlNCbGJtTnZaR1ZrSUdsdUlHSmhjMlUyTkNCdmJteDVJRzl1WTJVPQ==</ns0:createHeaderSecurityRequest>
</soap-env:Body>
```

what I want (message value encoded to base64 only once): request =

```
<soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <ns0:createHeaderSecurityRequest xmlns:ns0="http://www.blabla.com/">bXkgbWVzc2FnZSwgdGhhdCBuZWVkcyB0byBiZSBlbmNvZGVkIGluIGJhc2U2NCBvbmx5IG9uY2U=</ns0:createHeaderSecurityRequest>
</soap-env:Body>
```

I will be very grateful for any help

zeep 3.4.0
python 3.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `encode()` on your string.

```
request = client.create_message(client.service, 'createHeaderSecurity', message)
```

Zeep automatically encodes bytes data to base64.